# Count how many elements are empty lists per column in a Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For obtaining the statistics, I need to know how many missing elements there are per column. This includes empty lists and empty dictionaries. But, they are not counted in isna() so I need an alternative.

I get my data from line delimited jsons.

Edit:
A variation of the answer below worked for me:

```py
for col in var.columns:
    print(col + ": " + str(var[col].apply(lambda x: 1 if x is not None and len(x) == 0 else 0).sum()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can select such columns as a series and can apply a lambda function on it which returns 1 if `list/dict` is empty else 0.

And then you can sum then series.

Following is not tested

```py
#say you have df["col1"] which has lists as elements
df["col1"].apply(lambda x: return 1 if len(x) == 0 else return 0).sum()
```

Comment: Problem is, I do not know which columns may have them. Can I parse all columns and apply this or is there a better way?